# Finding savings in an Overlapping Generations model

Tags: macroeconomics, utility, optimization

I have not seen this question asked anywhere, so I'm posing it here in case anybody else (hopefully) can help me get to the answer. In a nutshell, my question is: **how do we arrive at the saving function in a canonical OLG with Cobb-Douglas utility?**

I'll explain my question in more detail: In Diamond's original OLG model, he describes saving as a function of the wage and the interest rate, so that:

$$
s_t=s_t(w_t,r_{t+1}).
$$

More specifically, when utility is Cobb-Douglas:

$$
U = (1-\beta) \cdot ln (C_{1,t}) + \beta \cdot ln(C_{2,t+1})
$$

Diamond concludes that the saving rate is a fixed ratio of the wage rate, such that:
$$
s_t= \beta \cdot w_t
$$
The same conclusion can found in most online references that cover the canonical OLG (for example, [here](https://economics.mit.edu/files/10232)).

However, I have not been able to find an explanation anywhere of **how one arrives at this equation for saving**. Most references that are available online, like the one I've just linked to, simply present a formula with no explanation as to its derivation. Meanwhile, [in his original paper](https://economics.mit.edu/files/10232), Diamond seems to jump to this conclusion (in page 1134) with no step-by-step explanation for how he arrived at this result for the Cobb-Douglas case.

Can anybody perhaps help me understand how this result comes about?

*(My motivation for asking is that I want to understand what would happen to consumption in a canonical OLG model if we supplemented the wage with an exogenous source of income "A", so that consumption of the young at time "t" were given by: $C_{1,t} = w_t -s_t + A$).*